# issues with Storing to array

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I was testing one of my classes, but for some reason I can't seem to cast an intiger from a 2d array to double. Here is my (very simplified) code:
In main.cpp

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include<string>
    #include "trajectories.h"
    int main()
    {
        std::string response;
        int numOfCoords;
        int speed;
        int ** coords;

        std::cout<<"enter the number of coordinates: ";
        std::cin>>numOfCoords;
        std::cout<<"enter speed: ";
        std::cin>>speed;

        coords=new int *[numOfCoords];
        for (int i=0; i<numOfCoords; i++)
        coords[i] = new int[2];

        for(int i=0; i<numOfCoords*2; i++)
        {
                if(i%2==0)
                std::cout<<"enter point "<<i/2<<".x : ";
                else
                std::cout<<"enter point "<<i/2<<".y : ";
                std::cin>>coords[i/2][i%2];
        }

        NPCTrajectory traj(numOfCoords, speed);
        traj.AddCoordinates(coords);

        std::cout<<coords[0][0]<<", "<<coords[0][1]<<std::endl;
        getch();

        double currentCoords[2];
        currentCoords[0]=double(coords[0][0]);
        currentCoords[1]=double(coords[0][1]);

for(;;)
    {

           traj.HandleEvents(currentCoords);
           std::cout<<"current coordinates : ("<<currentCoords[0]<<", "<<currentCoords[1]<<")"<<std::endl;
           std::cout<<"do you wish to continue? ";
           getch();
    }
    }
```

Trajectories.h contains class declaration only, so I believe it is irrelevant. Here is my trajectories.cpp

```
    #include "trajectories.h"

        int FPSCap=5;

        NPCTrajectory::NPCTrajectory(int npoints, int newSpeed)
        {
              numOfPoints=npoints;
              this->speed=newSpeed;
              points = new int * [npoints];
              for (int i=0; i<npoints; i++)
              points[npoints] = new int[2];
              state = 0;
              maxOffset=speed/FPSCap;
        }

        void NPCTrajectory::AddCoordinates(int ** coordinates)
        {
             for(int i=0;i<this->numOfPoints; i++)
             {
                     points[i][0]=coordinates[i][0];
                     points[i][1]=coordinates[i][1];
             }
        }
void NPCTrajectory::HandleEvents(double (&currentCoordinates)[2])
{
     if(state+1==numOfPoints) return;
     if(Distance(currentCoordinates[0], currentCoordinates[1], (double)points[state+1][0], (double)points[state+1][1])<maxOffset) state++;
     double ratio = maxOffset/Distance(currentCoordinates[0], currentCoordinates[1], (double)points[state+1][0], (double)points[state+1][1]);
     currentCoordinates[0]+=(points[state+1][0]-currentCoordinates[0])*ratio;
     currentCoordinates[1]+=(points[state+1][1]-currentCoordinates[1])*ratio;
}
```

Please note that removing command traj.AddCoordinates(coords) will make the problem disappear. Am I passing the array correctly to the function?

Comment: What, exactly is it doing, and what is it supposed to be doing?

Comment: @atk I have removed NPCTrajectory::move for clarity. Here I have stripped down the program to basic error cause. It is supposed to move a point towards another point based on the FPSCap defined globally and speed.

Comment: I am pleased the you narrowed it down to just under 100 lines of code. What was it like before?

Comment: Casting `int` to `double` is certainly not the problem. The problem is all this horrendous dynamic allocation and pointer nonsense!

Comment: @EdHeal I have just added NPCTrajectory::HandleEvents and added a few lines of code the end of main.cpp. Now it doesn't differ much from the original.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what is the standard way of operating with dynamically allocated arrays then?

Comment: @Walter Avoiding them.

Comment: You still have not described what behavior you expect and what behavior you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your constructor NPCTrajectory. Replace npoints with loop variable i. The following code:

```
for (int i=0; i<npoints; i++)
          points[npoints] = new int[2];
```

should be like:

```
for (int i=0; i<npoints; i++)
          points[i] = new int[2];
```

Because of this incorrect allocation, you are getting error (segmentation fault) in AddCoordinates function when you try to access points[i][0] with i=0 (assuming you are giving npoints>0 in NPCTrajectory).

Comment: Ned, you are a genius! I always have problems with spotting memory allocation errors. Thank you.